# Python geocode change my city names to weird ones

Tags: python, python-2.7, geocode

I try to get the lat/lon info for several cities following the guidance of https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy; however, it does not work for me as expected. When I input the list of city names, the location creates some wired names based on my cities but work normal for others. Then it complains UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128). the exact code is as below:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()
df=pd.read_csv('testgoo0122.csv') 
print df['google']
list1=df['google'].tolist()
print list1
for i in range(0,len(list1)):
    location = geolocator.geocode("'"+list1[i]+"'")
    print location

#I also tried, which has the exact same problem.
for i in range(0,len(df.google)):
    location=geolocator.geocode("'"+df.google[i]+"'")
    print location
```

The output looks like: so you can see when i first print city names (df['google'], it is normal; when i convert it to list, it is still normal; however, after the geocode function, the location looks wired. Can anyone help? many thanks!

```
 0    Kerugoya,Kirinyaga,KENYA
 1                   Mie,JAPAN
 2            Hhohho,SWAZILAND
 3                 Granma,CUBA
 4                Holguin,CUBA
 Name: google, dtype: object
 ['Kerugoya,Kirinyaga,KENYA', 'Mie,JAPAN', 'Hhohho,SWAZILAND', 'Granma,CUBA', 'Holguin,CUBA']

Kerugoya, Kirinyaga, Kenya
Japan, Luzerne County, Pennsylvania, 18221, United States of America
Hhohho, eSwatini Swaziland
Granma, Cuba
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "testgoogle2.py", line 30, in <module>
print location
```

Comment: By default, `Nominatim()` uses http://www.openstreetmap.org to resolve geodata. If you search for 'Mie, JAPAN' on openstreet.org, the first result is indeed "Japan, Luzerne County, Pennsylvania, 18221, United States of America." Dunno why.

Comment: Are you using Python 3?

Comment: @JamesSchinner Clearly not (look at the `print`s).

Comment: As for the Unicode error, look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20.

Comment: @DYZ Thanks. but do you know how to resolve the issue?

Comment: @JamesSchinner I use python2.7